# Is this inline block+text layout possible at all in React Native?

Tags: html, css, ios, react-native, layout

I'm trying to achieve the following layout in React Native (layout created successfully on web in HTML+CSS):

[image: target layout visualisation]

The tricky part is the gray breadcrumb element that should inline with the description. My code for the breadcrumb+description part is as follows:

```
 <Text style={styles.description}>
    <Text style={styles.quantity}>{quantity}</Text>
    {description}
 </Text>
```

styles.ts:

```
 description: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'light',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  quantity: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: Color.white,
    backgroundColor: Color.placeholder,
    borderRadius: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 400,
  },
```

It results in this:

[image]

As you can see, the `borderRadius` and `padding` properties get ignored on the `quantity` element.

I have also tried doing it with `View` elements instead of `Text` ones but the description simply goes fully to the next line when it overflows (classic block behaviour).

So, is there any trick/workaround to achieving this layout in RN? Thanks.

Comment: it's probably being overwritten by another style. Maybe try throwing an `!important` onto the value

Comment: So I provided an answer that used a snack to show how nested text would work, but I forgot about the gimmicks. For ios/android, there are some text styles that doesnt work but the work around would be to wrap the text in a view with a flex direction of row, and then take wrap the text in a view where you apply the styles the ios/android text wouldnt render

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the nested text in a view with a flex direction of row, and then go about wrapping the text component in a view ([demo](https://snack.expo.dev/8IlNuBEG6)):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Text } from 'react-native-paper';
const Color = {
  white: 'white',
  placeholder: 'blue',
};
const quantity = 50;
const description =
  'Once upon a time there was a story told that took a very long time to tell.';

const InlineText = ({ style, children, ...props }) => {
  style = StyleSheet.flatten(style)
  const textStyle = {
    ...style,
    // // remove styles that dont work on android/ios

    paddingHorizontal:null,
    marginHorizontal:null,
    borderRadius:null
  }
  return (
    <View style={[{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'},style]}>
      <Text  {...props} style={textStyle}>{children}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text style={styles.description}>
          {/*InlineText no longer inherits the parent text styles*/}
          <InlineText style={[styles.description,styles.quantity]}>{quantity}</InlineText>
          {description}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  description: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'light',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  quantity: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: Color.white,
    backgroundColor: Color.placeholder,
    borderRadius: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 3,
  },
});
```